# why some people use relative dirs using a dot, or dot and slash and others not?

Tags: html

This is maybe a kind of dumb question but I never knew why there are 3 ways to write the same.

For instance, show an image called `photo1.jpg` inside the `img` dir:

index.html

```
<img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="photo 1" />
<img src="/images/img_1.jpg" alt="photo 1" />
<img src="./images/img_1.jpg" alt="photo 1" />
```

Those 3 work but is one better than the other? why?

Edit, as some pointed out, the second one is an absolute path.

In that case what I want to know is what differences are between 1 or 3. Or they are interchangeable?

Comment: The second one isn't a relative url. It's absolute to the root of the site.

Comment: All three will create some problem, when there is any change in directory structure, Its batter to use full path from the http:/

Comment: @Harsh The second one already is a *full path*. Additionally adding the protocol and domain to that is really overkill and makes the document less portable (read: impossible to move anywhere else).

Comment: @distante *"Why some people do this"* is not something we can answer. 1 and 3 are relative paths, number 2 is an absolute path. Take your pick depending on your situation.

Comment: @deceze try the second path when you have URL that is rewrite using .htaccess file.

Comment: @Harsh Wut? That is pretty irrelevant here.

Comment: @deceze ok, so the second will just work if the images dir is in the root. In that case what I want to know is what differences are between 1 or 3. Or they are interchangeable?

Comment: There's indeed no practical difference between `foo` and `./foo` that I'm aware of. `.` is an ancient convention which lives on in URLs, but is not actually particularly useful in URLs (much more so on *NIX command lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the second one is not a relative path, images should be in the root folder.

The first and the third one are the same, dot represents current folder.